# button in uwp not showing when i launch

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

ok so the problem is that my button is not showing when I enter debug mode. when I design it shows but not when I Launch. The other pages buttons work fine just this.

```html
<Grid Background="#FF6C0000">
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="162" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="425" Source="ctu headers.png" Visibility="Visible"/>
        <Button x:Name="backbutton" Content="Back"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Height="50" BorderBrush="White" FontSize="18" Click="Button_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <AcrylicBrush TintColor="#CC918989"/>
            </Button.Background>

        </Button>


    </Grid>
```

Comment: Are you setting some Visibility for this button from code behind?

Comment: Try to open the Visual Studio Live Visual Tree, find your button node and right click on it, select "Show Properties" to view whether the Button is still visible.